# Sibling component styling with styled-components

Tags: styled-components

This is quite a simple case which I can't, for some reason, get to work. I have a `styled-components` Container, and I'd like to define the styles of `p` inside that container like so:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  & p {
    margin: 0;
    & + & {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
  }
`
```

So, I would expect whenever there's more that on `p` inside the `Container`, that the second `p` would get a `top-margin`, but this doesn't happen.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-bash-rnr0i?file=/src/App.js:63-183).

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the example in codesandbox is wrong or missing?
Could you please update it, so i could take a look

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I think I shared it without having saved first... :) It should be OK now.

Comment: Could you please write in CSS what you try to achieve? I'm not sure if I understand it correct. Then I could help you to "transform" it into styled components.

Comment: It's quite simple really. I want `p` elements inside the `Container` to have `margin: 0`. But if there are more than one `p` elements, I want all from the 2nd till the last one to have a `top-margin: 10px` so that there's space between paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just inverted the condition.
Is this want you want?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-albattani-j38me)

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  background: grey;
  & p:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  & p {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Container>
        <p>Line One</p>
        <p>Line Two</p>
        <p>Line Two</p>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This is almost what I wanted, so with a small modification I got it - the end result is `& p { margin: 0; &:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 10px; } }`. So, even though I'm still curious why my original code doesn't work (perhaps someone will still chip in), I will accept your answer. Thanks again!